Ansible: Usage of with_items in a more compact way?
Considering the following test playbook:
---
- name: Playbook
  hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    plugins:
      - name: diff
        enabled: true
        dependencies:
          - python3-jsonpatch
          - python3-kubernetes
        repository:
          name: helm-diff
          org: databus23
        version: v3.9.6
      - name: git
        enabled: false
        repository:
          name: helm-git
          org: aslafy-z
        version: v0.16.0
  tasks:
    - name: Loop
      block:
        - name: List plugin names
          ansible.builtin.debug:
            msg: '{{ item.name }}'
          when: item.enabled
          with_items: '{{ plugins }}'

        - name: List dependencies
          ansible.builtin.debug:
            msg: '{{ item }}'
          with_items: "{{ plugins | selectattr('enabled', 'eq', true) | selectattr('dependencies', 'defined') | map(attribute='dependencies') }}"

Which produces the expected results:
TASK [List plugin names] ***
ok: [localhost] => (item={'name': 'diff', 'enabled': True, 'dependencies': ['python3-jsonpatch', 'python3-kubernetes'], 'repository': {'name': 'helm-diff', 'org': 'databus23'}, 'version': 'v3.9.6'}) =>
  msg: diff

TASK [List dependencies] ***
ok: [localhost] => (item=python3-jsonpatch) =>
  msg: python3-jsonpatch
ok: [localhost] => (item=python3-kubernetes) =>
  msg: python3-kubernetes

Is there a better way to render the use of with_items more compact into second task, ideally with a combined with condition, as used into first task?
I will have multiple tasks using the same with_items loops listed above, I don't know if there is a way to group multiple tasks under the same with_items loop.
Edit: While @larks's suggestion is a great approach, I ended using the following conditions which IMO, produces a clean readable code:
  tasks:
    - name: Loop
      block:
        - name: List plugin names
          ansible.builtin.debug:
            msg: '{{ item.name }}'
          loop: "{{ plugins }}"
          when: item.enabled

        - name: List dependencies
          ansible.builtin.debug:
            msg: '{{ item.dependencies }}'
          loop: '{{ plugins }}'
          when:
            - item.enabled
            - item.dependencies is defined


Does this answer your question? Issue looping on block containing a set of tasks in Ansible. Since Ansible doesn't allow to use loops on a block, you could include the required tasks into a separate task file and include it in a loop as shown by the link.

Thank you @AlexanderPletnev. I looked at the provided example, but I'm not sure I understand how to simplify the with_items: "{{ plugins | selectattr('enabled', 'eq', true) | selectattr('dependencies', 'defined') | map(attribute='dependencies') }}" conditional, but implementing a when.

If you use the json_query filter, you could write your task like this:
- name: List dependencies
  ansible.builtin.debug:
    msg: "{{ item }}"
  loop: "{{ plugins | json_query('[].dependencies[]') }}"

That produces as output:
TASK [List dependencies] **********************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=python3-jsonpatch) => {
    "msg": "python3-jsonpatch"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=python3-kubernetes) => {
    "msg": "python3-kubernetes"
}

Depending on your goal, you could drop the loop and instead write:
- name: List dependencies
  ansible.builtin.debug:
    msg: "{{ plugins | json_query('[].dependencies[]') }}"

Which produces a single merged list of dependencies:
TASK [List dependencies] **********************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        "python3-jsonpatch",
        "python3-kubernetes"
    ]
}


Thank you @larks for the improved code. Upvoted and accepted as answer.
